# Property Setter and Getter Not able to overwrite

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I have this objective-C header file for an Animal class:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Animal : NSObject

@property NSString *name;
@property NSString *favoriteFood;
@property NSString *sound;

@property float weight;

-(instancetype) initWithName:(NSString *) defaultName;

-(void) getInfo;

-(float) getWeightInKg: (float) weightInLbs;

-(NSString *) talkToMe: (NSString *) myName;

-(int) getSum: (int) num1
   nextNumber: (int) num2;

@end
```

And for some reason when I try to overwrite the setter or getter methods for @property NSString *name in the implementation file of the Animal class, I am not able to do so and it gives me a warning saying "Writable atomic property 'name' cannot pair a synthesized getter with a user defined setter". Am I doing something wrong here? Because I thought the @property creates a ivar and setter and getter methods automatically which you can override in your implementation file. Can someone please help me with this issue. Thank you so much for the help in advance!

Comment: Try changing the definition to `@property (readonly) NSString *name;`. This way the compiler won't generate a setter, leaving you to implement it yourself.

Comment: Ok but what if I don't add any attributes to the property (such as strong, nonatomic, etc.). Without those attributes for the properties am I not allowed to create my own setter and getter methods?

Comment: The default is `readwrite` which means the compiler will create (aka. synthesize) one for you. `strong` and `nonatomic` define how these synthesized methods treat the inner variable. `readwrite` is the default, hence the collision with your custom setter.

Comment: If you have an atomic property you can't override just one of the setter or getter, you need to override both of them or neither.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your properties as:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *favoriteFood;
@property (nonatomic) NSString *sound;
```

Comment: So if I put it as nonatomic and I only override my setter method, will my getter method still be created automatically or will it not even exist and I have to implement it on my own? My understanding now is that if the attribute of my property is atomic then I have to override both setter and getter methods, but if it is nonatomic if I don't override both since they will be created automatically anyways?

Comment: If you define your property as "atomic" (default setting) then you must provide both setter and getter, or let the compiler generate both of them for you. If you set it as "nonatomic", then you can implement setter or getter, or both, and the compiler will generate the missing setter or getter for you.

Comment: you may find this acticle useful as well: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/property-values/